# tcpdf custom footer adjustment

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, tcpdf

I am generating a invoice pdf using tcpdf in php codeigniter framework, i am using html template and then writing to pdf.

Invoice pdf has company name then addreess , then item list and then price and sign etc.

look at case 1 - [image]

if there is only 1 item in pdf , then the price and sign box should be on bottom

Look at case 2 -

[image]

pdf has many items , and then if space left on bottom then footer is on bottom otherwise it should be on 2 page but on footer like case 3

[image]

**My problem is i dont know how to give proper difference between items and bottom sign part , else pdf is generating FINE!!!!**

my code is

```
    public function generatePDF($html1 = NULL, $name = 'PDF', $path = null, $action = 'D') 
{
    ob_start();
    ob_clean();
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    require_once(APPPATH . 'third_party/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');  
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setFooterData(array(0, 64, 0), array(0, 64, 128));
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
    // set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
    // set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
    // set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
    $pdf->SetFont('stsongstdlight','B', 12);
    // add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetLineStyle( array( 'width' => 2, 'color' => array(0,0,0)));
    $pdf->Line(0,0,$pdf->getPageWidth(),0); 
    $pdf->Line($pdf->getPageWidth(),0,$pdf->getPageWidth(),$pdf->getPageHeight());
    $pdf->Line(0,$pdf->getPageHeight(),$pdf->getPageWidth(),$pdf->getPageHeight());
    $pdf->Line(0,0,0,$pdf->getPageHeight());

    // output the HTML content
    $pdf->writeHTML($html1, true, false, true, false, '');
    $pdf->Output($name . '.pdf', $action);
}
```

Comment: You should probably make that in a footer, where you check that you have still enough of space and write it only on the last page.

Comment: yes bt i dnt know how.. can help??